# Construct a deterministic finite automation

Tags: automata, finite-automata

The question asks to:

> construct a DFA which accepts exactly $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6} + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+1$ many members of $\{0, 1\}^n$ for every n.

I have no idea where to start to constructing the DFA, could you give some directions?
By the way, how many states should this DFA have?

Comment: First, figure out an example of a language that has this property; once you have that, the DFA shouldn't be too hard. Hint: think of a question for which the answer is $n(n-1)(n-2)/3!$ and a closely related question for which the answer is $n(n-1)/2!$.

Comment: The fractions are curious only at first glance. Check your formulary to find a "natural" way for them to appear. (It is pretty clear that the number of states is all but immaterial to the question.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Here is a regular language which "accepts" exactly $n$ members of $\{0,1\}^n$ for every $n$: $0^* 1 0^*$. For example, for $n=4$ we have the strings $0001,0010,0100,1000$. The minimal DFA for this language contains three states.